# Struts 2 - Get a complete URL of the Application

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2

I'm using a third party API which requires sending a complete URL in one of the JSP. I need to set the URL like

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/add.action
```

I can implement the `/MyWebApp/add.action` using `<s:action/>`

But how to get the `http://localhost:8080` in Struts2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`s:url`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/url.html) tag. Include the attribute `forceAddSchemeHostAndPort="true"`.